# Capture stderr into a pipe from command expansion

Tags: bash

I have a program that returns answers on stdout and errors on stderr.
Unfortunately the program ends by emitting some text on stderr even if successful.

I would like to store the program output in a variable using command expansion as:
ans=$(prog) 2>&1 | grep -v success

This doesn't work. Tried putting 2>&1 in the parens, but as I suspected $ans then
gets the success text.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

Not sure, what you trying to get, but probably this is your command:

```
ans=$(prog 2>&1 | grep -v success)
```

If you want to filter 'success' only from standard error stream, you could use something like this:

```
ans=$({ ./foo 3>&2 2>&1 >&3- | grep -v success; } 2>&1)
```

And just in case, as noted in [BashFAQ/002](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/002):

> What you cannot do is capture stdout in one variable, and stderr in another, using only FD redirections. You must use a temporary file (or a named pipe) to achieve that one.

Comment: That will probably work for my case, thanks. But if the result of prog also returns some text with "success" in it, it will not work.

Comment: You said nothing about the possible program output and about what you want to get in `ans` variable. Do you want to filter out all lines with 'success' word from error stream only?

Comment: I updated my answer. If your question is exhausted, you could accept the answer.

Comment: Thanks again! I suspected that I needed to do the std'dance you present above, no time to test right now. Would be nice yo have some